# Dalekjs and running Nodejs Functions

Tags: node.js, dalekjs

I am writing code that runs a test and if the results come back a certain way I'd like to send an email to myself.

Unfortunately, every-time DalekJS runs through my code it seems to skip over the email function.

Here's what my code looks like. I'm skipping over the login and open site part for security purposes. All of that part works fine. The code hangs on test.wait(15000).

This is the require code `var emailjs = require('./seeifemail');`

```
test.click('#header_navbar_account_landers')
test.wait(15000)
test.execute(function() {
    if ($('#select2-chosen-6').text() != "United States of America") {
      $('#select2-chosen-6').text("United States of America")
      $('#select2-chosen-6').change()
    }
    })
    var msgCnt = parseInt($('.loaded-total').text(), 10);
    if (msgCnt > 0) {
      emailjs.magicFn
      return 'done'

    } else {
      alert('it didn\'t work')
      return 'done'
    }

  test.wait(20000)
  test.done();
```

Here is what seeifemail looks like.

```
var email = require('emailjs/email');
var server = email.server.connect({
user: "username",
password: "password",
host: "smtp.gmail.com",
ssl: true
});

 module.exports = {
 magicFn: function() {


server.send({
  text: "i hope this works",
  from: "you <username@your-email.com>",
  to: "email@email.com",
  cc: "else <else@your-email.com>",
  subject: "testing emailjs"
}, function(err, message) {
  console.log(err || message);
});
```

Thanks for your help in advanced!

Comment: Just to clarify, is `'done'` returned, i.e. is `msgCnt > 0`? If you, did you try including a callback in your `server.send()`? It might be the case, that your script terminates (caused by `return`) before the email can be sent.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on my comment: Maybe you have to wait for your `server.send()` to finish before you can `return` and thereby (maybe) terminate your app:

```
test.click('#header_navbar_account_landers');
test.wait(15000);
test.execute(function() {
  if ($('#select2-chosen-6').text() != "United States of America") {
    $('#select2-chosen-6').text("United States of America");
    $('#select2-chosen-6').change();
  }
});
var msgCnt = parseInt($('.loaded-total').text(), 10);
if (msgCnt > 0) {
  emailjs.magicFn(function(err, message) {
    return 'done';
  });

} else {
  alert('it didn\'t work');
  return 'done';
}
test.wait(20000);
test.done();
```

And then:

```
var email = require('emailjs/email');
var server = email.server.connect({
  user: "username",
  password: "password",
  host: "smtp.gmail.com",
  ssl: true
});

module.exports = {
  magicFn: function(callback) {
    server.send({
      text: "i hope this works",
      from: "you <username@your-email.com>",
      to: "email@email.com",
      cc: "else <else@your-email.com>",
      subject: "testing emailjs"
    }, callback);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Removing the return statement or adding something in between it doesn't seem to have any effect. Its still hanging at the wait and never running the function magicFn

Comment: Judging from the documentation, you did not define a valid test case for DalekJS. Your `if then` actually should be an [assertion](http://dalekjs.com/docs/assertions.html), shouldn't it?

Comment: yeah msgCnt >0 does return true. If i were to run `if (msgCnt >0) { alert('something'); } ' It will return the alert. Likewise when the value is false it successfully runs the false code. The problem with assertions is they don't seem to return a true of false value but show up in the command line tool as passed or failed. So as a result I can't seem to have a function run as an effect of an assertion value. That's why I ended up using the test.execute method because it supposedly allows non dalekjs functions to run. Which it does but doesn't seem to run nodejs functions.